# Ciclar hilos sincronizados en java?

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un programa que simule una mesa de 5 personas, en la cual 2 comen mientras las otras 3 esperan.
Sin embargo, se ciclan solo dos veces y corre las mismas posiciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imágenes con código fuente, copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta.

Comment: puedes poner el código donde creas los hilos.